# ldap equal filtrer search for an attribute with alpha numeric value failing

Tags: ldap, equals, spring-ldap, ldap-query, opendj

Consider the two entries :

1.

```
dn: ou=system,ou=test,dc=ent,dc=my,dc=com
createdbyuser: rootAgent
createdondate: 31-May-2018 15:58:31 IST
name: system1
objectClass: top
objectClass: orgentity
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: system
```

2.

```
dn: ou=system,ou=test,dc=ent,dc=my,dc=com
createdbyuser: rootAgent
createdondate: 31-May-2018 15:58:31 IST
name: example/system1
objectClass: top
objectClass: orgentity
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: system
```

My search query:

```
(&
(ou:dn:=system)
(name=system1)
(objectclass=orgentity)
)
```

Expected : Only first (1) entry should be the output

Actual: But we are getting both the entries

And I am Using **OpenDJ Server 3.5.1**

Comment: Not all LDAP server implementations support Extensible Match Rules. (Like AD).

Answer (score 1):

The result is expected. The 'name' attribute is subtyped by many attributes including 'ou'. You should avoid using the 'name' attribute in entries. AFAIK, there is no standard schema that make use of this attribute. It's used only in searches to retrieve or filter on any attribute that can be a name.